# Checking for the sphericity assumption of repeated-measures ANOVA?

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, anova

I have run a repeated-measures ANOVA below:

```
ANOVAtest <- anova_test(data=Book19,
formula=Proportionofcorrecttrials~Condition*Firsttargetboundary, 
dv=Proportionofcorrecttrials, wid=ID,within=c(Condition,Firsttargetboundary))
```

I have then tried to check the sphericity assumption by entering the following command:

`get_anova_table(ANOVAtest, correction = c("auto"))`

However, the output produced is this:

[enter image description here][1]

Which is fine, except that it is not displaying the results from the test for sphericity?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, please check your question as we don't see your output. While you edit your question, feel free to add the `r` tag, because this is a question about the R language and not the Rstudio software.

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: @Gowachin the issue is solved! Thanks so much! 

> ANOVAtest

ANOVA Table (type III tests)

$ANOVA
                      Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   pes
1                  Condition   2  28  2.427 1.07e-01       0.148
2           Distancetotarget   4  56 12.314 2.99e-07     * 0.468
3 Condition:Distancetotarget   8 112  0.776 6.25e-01       0.052
$`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity`
                      Effect     W     p p<.05
1                  Condition 0.987 0.920      
2           Distancetotarget 0.598 0.704      
3 Condition:Distancetotarget 0.048 0.577      etc

Comment: @StupidWolf the issue is solved! Thanks so much! > ANOVAtest ANOVA Table (type III tests) $ANOVA Effect DFn DFd F p p<.05 pes 1 Condition 2 28 2.427 1.07e-01 0.148 2 Distancetotarget 4 56 12.314 2.99e-07 * 0.468 3 Condition:Distancetotarget 8 112 0.776 6.25e-01 0.052 $Mauchly's Test for Sphericity Effect W p p<.05 1 Condition 0.987 0.920 2 Distancetotarget 0.598 0.704 3 Condition:Distancetotarget 0.048 0.577 etc